# CSS absolute positioning on a site using percentage based heights and horizontal scrolling

Tags: css, positioning, horizontal-scrolling

Is there a way to left position my elements using only CSS using a percentage of the complete document width, not just the browser width?

I am creating a horizontal scroll website where all element heights and alignment from the top are set using percentages — this is to accommodate all browser sizes and to ensure the ratio is kept for all elements.

If I attempt to change the left (or right) alignment of an element on a page using something like;

```
#my_element {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5%;
    width: 34%
    left: 10%;
}
```

This will be 10% of the width of the browser window, not the actual width of the body or html element — which makes sense in standard vertical scrolling websites, but doesn't help me.

My current workaround is to position left using JavaScript doing something like;

```
$('#my_element').css('left', $(document).width() / 100 * 10) //Position to 10% of the page.
```

This works but has caused a few issues when JavaScript doesn't load quick enough or when I want to animate various elements using CSS animations.

Comment: not sure i understand your question, but an absolutely positioned element is positioned relative to the closest positioned (i.e. - non static position element) so you can give the parent a position:relative property value.

Comment: The parent will always be `body` which seems to never have a width greater than the browser width, at least as far as CSS is concerned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set your element's `width` with a percentage, it is measured against that element's parent. So below, the `body` element is 100% width of the browser and `div.box` is 50% width of the `body` element.

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    div.box { width: 50% }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="box">
</body>
</html>
```

You can actually change the width of the `body` and `html` elements.

So if you have, for instance, four "slides" or "panels" that you want to be 100% width of the browser, you can give the `html` element 400% width, the `body` 100% width (still 400% of the browser because its parent is the `html` element), and each slide 25% width.

[Here is a fiddle with an example.](http://jsfiddle.net/flackend/cXW5w/)

The only problem I see is if you have say three slides, your `html` element would be 300% and each slide 33.33333...%. So you won't have a nice clean number document.

Fun fact, you can also mess with any element, like `<head>` or `<script>`. I.e., You can display the content of a `<script>` just like any other element by changing its default `display: none` to `inline` or `block`...[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/flackend/w2pnL/)

Comment: A combination of your solution and the first comment on my question got me where I needed to go, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed possible, to be cross browser compatible you will need to have width and height set in the html and body tags as well.

[Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/Abyssoft/FAHSj/)

```
html {
    width:100.01%;
    height:100.01%;
}
body {
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
}
div#normaldiv {
    border: 1px blue solid;
}
div#absolutediv {
    border: 1px red solid;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5%;
    left: 10%;
    width: 34%;
    height: 20%;
}
​
```

The sample shows this in action, where the iframe defines the window. The use of the .01 to the normal 100% handles most pixel issues. By setting the values for html and body you also hand the has layout issue present in IE6.

Comment: That still appears to be pushing left based on the browser width, not the parent element width, thanks though.